# Cant pass variable for some reason? PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, chart.js

Some reason when i call `$_POST['xalue']` it will only return the first index of `$xaxis`.

```
$xaxis = '["-100","-100","240","1056","3560","-650","5980.5","1020"]'
```

im just trying to pass the information so when the button is pressed to add the dashboard i can pass the data along. Thank you

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ID From users WHERE Username='$user'");
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$data = $fetch{"ID"};

$sql = "SELECT dashboardname FROM dashboards WHERE dashboarduserID=$data";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$addarray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    global $xaxis;
    echo $xaxis;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($addarray, $row['dashboardname']);
    }
    echo '<form method="post">';?>
    <input type="text" name="xvalue" value="<?php echo $xaxis ?>">
    <?php
    echo 'Add current graph to :';
    echo '<select name="addgraph">';
    foreach ($addarray as $item) {
        echo '<option value="' . $item . '">' . $item . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="addtodash" value="Add">';
    echo '</form>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
    if (isset($_REQUEST["addtodash"])) {
    $xaxis = $_POST['xvalue'];
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ID From users WHERE Username='$user'");
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $data = $fetch{"ID"};
    $nameofdash = $_POST['addgraph'];
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO dashboardsdata (userid,dashboardname,xdata,ydata) VALUES ($data,\"$nameofdash\",\"$xaxis\",\"$yaxis\");");
    echo "done";
}
```

Comment: You can't echo an array.

Comment: Its a string of an array. sorry should've said

Comment: Where is `$_POST['xalue']` in the code?

Comment: PUT IT IN YOUR QUESTION! Nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL-injection. You should learn to use prepared queries with `bind_param` instead of substituting variables into the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotes in `$xvalue` will match the double quotes that are used to delimit the `value="..."` attribute. You need to encode them:

```
<input type="text" name="xvalue" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($xaxis); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You problably need to do two things:

1. As Barmar said, you cannot "simply" echo an array. You need to parse it into value, for example

   `value="implode(';', $array)"`
2. Another option is to declare multiple inputs, each with one value for your array.